# Unexpected token error in powershell, executes fine in PS3+ having an issue on 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Im working on a script to query some data from a csv in powershell and its working fine on machines with Powershell 3+ but we have clients with some machines that have 2.0 and I am trying to get it compatible.

This particular line of code is causing the error:

```
    $nameCheck += Import-Csv C:\temp\tokens.csv | Where-Object {$_. 'Customer Name' -clike "*$cid*"} | Select-Object 'Customer Name'
```

The error its giving is:

> Unexpected token '.' in expression or statement.
>   At C:\temp\tokenQueryv2.ps1:29 char:64
>   + $nameCheck += Import-Csv C:\temp\tokens.csv | Where-Object {$_. <<<<  'Customer Name' -clike "*$cid*"} | Select-Object 'Customer Name'
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Based on the char position in the error it looks like it dosent like the `{$_. '...'` after the `Where-Object` I am assuming there is some different needed syntax for this on PS2.0 I  am just struggling to find it in any online resources. If anyone knows or has any experience with something like this any input is much welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell v2 does not allow space after member lookup operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Where-Object {$_. 'Customer Name' -clike "*$cid*"}
```

to

```
Where-Object {$_.'Customer Name' -clike "*$cid*"}
```

I'm surprised that PSv3 does support a space after the `.`